# Python How to declare each line in file as a variable

Tags: python

i am trying to seperate each line of file and create a new file with the content.

this is content of my data.txt

```
210CT 201707001 Michael_Tan 0 17.5
210CT 201707001 Michael_Tan 0 20.0
210CT 201707001 Michael_Tan 70.0 35.0

210CT 201707002 Jasmine_Tang 0 20.5
210CT 201707002 Jasmine_Tang 0 30.0
210CT 201707002 Jasmine_Tang 80.0 38.5
```

this is my code attempt but i'm stuck as i don't know what to do next.

```
    with open(home + "\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\Student's Mark.txt", "w") as c:
    with open(home + "\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\data.txt", "r") as d:
        for line in d:
            module, stdId , atdName , totalMark , mark = line.strip().split()
```

i want my Student's Mark.txt content to be (the order of the number must be like in the output)

```
210CT 201707001 Michael_Tan  70.0 17.5 20.0 35.0
210CT 201707002 Jasmine_Tang 80.0 20.5 30.0 38.6
```

is it possible to do this?

NOTE: PLEASE FEEL FREE TO CHANGE THE CODE HOWEVER YOU WANT AS LONG AS THE CONTENT IS  CORRECT

Comment: Is there any particular order of those numbers at the end in the output?

Comment: What is the logic behind the transformation?

Comment: @Qeek yes the order of those number must be in the output

Comment: @COLDSPEED i am just trying to check if the output i want  is it possible to do it. :)

Comment: @JasperStaTham This doesn't help me. For example, I want to know why Michalel Tan does not have 40.0 in the output.

Comment: @COLDSPEED the  number in  michael_tan 35.0, 40.0, 70.0. the number is overwritting itself and i just want the final number which is 70.0

Comment: What i see is the first number in the output is the highest `totalMark` while the rest of numbers are all `marks`. Is that correct?

Comment: @COLDSPEED i edited the question so it wont be confusing . sorry about that

Comment: @Queek , yes you're correct

Comment: "with the content of my desire" is not a sufficient description of what you're trying to do. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry about that, i don't know what word to use for my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution first save all records into ordered dictionary when it process whole file the it will save it. Right now I used as key into dictionary the `stdId` (I suppose it is unique among all students).

```
from collections import OrderedDict
# Use OrderedDict so the order of inserted students is preserved
records = OrderedDict()
with open("in.txt", "r") as r:
    for line in r:
        # Skip empty lines
        if line == "\n":
            continue
        module, stdId, atdName, totalMark, mark = line.strip().split()
        if stdId not in records:
            # Create new record per student
            records[stdId] = {"keep": (module, stdId, atdName), "totalMarks":  totalMark, "marks": [mark]}
        else:
            # Update student record of existing students in the dictionary
            # First replace old totalMark 
            records[stdId]["totalMark"] = totalMark 
            # Add to list current mark
            records[stdId]["marks"].append(mark)

with open("out.txt", "w") as w:
    # Iterate through records and save it
    for record in records.values():
        w.write(" ".join(record["keep"]) +
                " " + record["totalMark"] +
                " " + " ".join(record["marks"]) +
                "\n")
```

Note: tested in Python 3.6